# ValueError: shapes (7,1) and (209,209) not aligned

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

```py
    Yh = np.squeeze(np.asarray(Yh))

    dcost_Yh = - (np.divide(Y, Yh ) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - Yh))    
        
    dcost_Z2 =  np.multiply(dcost_Yh,dSigmoid(ch["Z2"]))
    print(dcost_Z2.T.shape[0])
    print(parameters["W2"].shape[0])
    dcost_A1 =  np.dot(parameters["W2"].T,dcost_Z2.T)
```

I got this error. I know why it gives this error bu I couldn't resolve it.
why I compute wrong ?? please help me .
here is my cost.

```py
 sam=Y.shape[1]
   
    AL = np.squeeze(np.asarray(AL))
    

    cost = (1./sam) * (-np.dot(Y,np.log(AL).T) - np.dot(1-Y, np.log(1-AL).T))    
    print(cost.shape[0])    



    return cost
```

can someone help me ?

error:
`  24     print(dcost_Z2.T.shape[0])

25     print(parameters["W2"].shape[0])

---> 26     dcost_A1 =  np.dot(parameters["W2"].T,dcost_Z2.T)

```
27     dcost_W2 = 1./ch['A1'].shape[1] * np.dot(dcost_Z2,ch['A1'].T)
```

28     dcost_b2 = 1./ch['A1'].shape[1] * np.dot(dcost_Z2,

np.ones([dcost_Z2.shape[1],1]))

<**array_function** internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (7,1) and (209,209) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 209 (dim 0)`

Comment: It is hard to debug without knowing more information about the variables.

Comment: I have added error. what else knowledge you need ?

Comment: Values of Yh and Y I believe, I want to be able to reproduce the error on my own console before trying anything.

Comment: can I send you message?

Comment: Sure, no problem! How do you want to send? I'm not sure if they have this feature

Comment: e-mail  telegram ,discord or whatsapp ? doesn't matter for me . which one you want?

Comment: ryolo2018#5882 is my discord

Comment: I can't send friendship. kraldinazor#2075  is my discord

Comment: can you reach me please

Comment: Just sent the request